# Почему не выдает роль в дискорде?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, role

Есть бот, на нем все права от discord.api до серверных прав. Когда я пытаюсь выдать роль, пишет, что нету прав, но они есть. В чем проблема?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\c_210\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\projects\python\BOT LEHA\main.py", line 47, in on_button_click
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\c_210\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\c_210\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

---код---

````
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    guild = bot.get_guild(interaction.guild.id)
    if interaction.component.id == "getrole":
            member = interaction.author
            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=861376131512795158)
            channel = bot.get_channel(903195927819468820)
            #role = guild.get_role(861376131512795158)

            if not role in member.roles:
                role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=861376131512795158)
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await interaction.respond(content="Welcome!")
                await channel.send(f"{member} получил роль -™")
            else:
                await interaction.respond(content="You alredy in our team!")```
````

Comment: покажи список ролей сервера и роли бота

Answer (score 0):

Роль нужно было выше всех поставить)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]